# Twilio Route Inbound Call before Answering

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-twiml

Is there a way to enqueue a Twilio inbound call before answering it?

Currently I am enqueueing a call (in TwiML app voice callback) with...

```
        $enqueue = $voiceResponse->enqueue('',[
            'workflowSid' => $workflowSid,
            'action' => $actionUrl,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'waitUrl' => $waitUrl,
            'waitUrlMethod' => 'GET'
        ])->task(json_encode($customTaskAttributes));
```

Where the wait url generates this TwiML...

```
        $voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse;
        $queueEntry = $queueEntryRepo->find($queueEntryId);
        $voiceResponse->say('Thanks for calling.  Please wait while we direct your call');
        $voiceResponse->play('http://com.twilio.sounds.music.s3.amazonaws.com/ClockworkWaltz.mp3');
        $xml = $voiceResponse->asXml();
```

What I would like to do is run the task router workflow *before* the call is answered.  So the call is not answered until there is an agent on the other end.  So no wait music, no announcement, just the agent answering knowing who is calling.

Is this possible? It seems to me I have seen this in the Twilio docs but I simply cannot find it now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out why I thought you could route a call before it was answered.  The <Pause> verb documentation says that if it is the first verb in the TwiML document, Twilio will wait the specified number of seconds before picking up the call.

I initially thought I could use this verb to allow the call to be routed (i.e. <Enqueue>'ed) before the call was picked up.

But no, this is not possible.  I can't imagine what the use case is for waiting for a fixed number of seconds before picking up the call, but using that delay to line up someone to answer the call is not one of them.  At least using all the Twilio task router machinery.  I suppose you could roll your own task router to do this.